# java applet HTTP download file can not work

Tags: java, applet

i write simple applet to download file from HTTP URL.
In Eclipse or Netbeans, it 's work well and can download file to d://abc//123.iso on my HDD.
This is my code :

```
public class download {
public static void saveUrl(final String filename, final String urlString)
        throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    BufferedInputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream fout = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(urlString).openStream());
        fout = new FileOutputStream(filename,true);

        final byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        int count;
            fout.write(data, 0, count);

    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
        if (fout != null) {
            fout.close();
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
public class HelloWorldApplet extends Applet
{
   public void paint (Graphics g)
   {
      g.drawString ("Download file", 25, 50);
String url ="http://downloads.asterisk.org/pub/telephony/asterisk-now/AsteriskNOW-612-current-32.iso";
                    String file_out = "d:\\abc\\123.iso"; 
                        download.saveUrl(file_out, url);

   }
}
```

==========================

But when export to jar file and run with html, browser can creat new file 123.iso on my HDD but the size of this file is always 2 Kbps. i think it do not download anything. 
 Please help me
 Thanks so much
P/s : i try to sign jar file with jarsigner but it does not solve the problem

Comment: You do a write without a read, you don't loop until EOF, you measure the file size in Kbps (kilobits per second), and you do the I/O inside the `paint()` method of an Applet? And you use `count` without initializing it, so this code won't even compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm skeptical as to the code above doing anything at all as posted, if even compiling, here's the solution I use for doing automatic update downloads of large (>100 MB) files:

```
            HttpGet httpGet;
            RequestConfig requestConfig;
            getProxySettings();

            //Check to see if there is a proxy availabble. 
            if (!LicensePreloader.proxyAddr.equals("")) {
                requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                        .setSocketTimeout(5000)
                        .setConnectTimeout(5000)
                        .setConnectionRequestTimeout(5000)
                        .setProxy(new HttpHost(LicensePreloader.proxyAddr, LicensePreloader.proxyPort))
                        .build();

            } else {
                //No proxy was available, just use regular internet. 
                requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                        .setSocketTimeout(5000)
                        .setConnectTimeout(5000)
                        .setConnectionRequestTimeout(5000)
                        .build();
            }
            httpGet = new HttpGet(this.remoteUrl);
            HttpResponse response;
            InputStream remoteContentStream = null;
            OutputStream localFileStream = null;
            try {
                httpGet.setConfig(requestConfig);
                response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

                //This builds the content of our file we're downloading. 
                remoteContentStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
                long fileSize = response.getEntity().getContentLength();
                File dir = localFile.getParentFile();
                dir.mkdirs();

                localFileStream = new FileOutputStream(localFile);
                //Set the buffer, in our use case, it's always the deafult 8192 bytes.
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                int sizeOfChunk;
                int amountComplete = 0;
                //Simply loop through and download the file in 'chunks' 
                while ((sizeOfChunk = remoteContentStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    localFileStream.write(buffer, 0, sizeOfChunk);
                    amountComplete += sizeOfChunk;
                    updateProgress(amountComplete, fileSize);

                }
                return localFile;
            } finally {
                //Make sure to clean everything up. 
                try {
                    if (remoteContentStream != null) {
                        remoteContentStream.close();
                    }
                    if (localFileStream != null) {
                        localFileStream.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    //If we're here, it's likely because the internet conneciton
                    //couldn't be established, or it was cut short in the middle. 
                    ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
                    failed();
                }
            }
        }
```

This is obviously overkill for your application, and you can probably just forget all the proxy business, but I kept it in there for completeness sake. There are a couple helper methods I didn't include, but again, they're almost all exclusively for proxy handling.

good luck!

Comment: thanks for your help. I think you are correct. after try to another download link ( <100 mbps), everything work well.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing one the first read in the input. You need to write the file until the input is empty.

Try this while in you code

`while ((count = in.read(data)) != -1) {
    fout.write(data, 0, count);
    ...
}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i have try  but it can not solve the problem.